# Pin an application to an Amazon Trust Services CA

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ca

During my search to pin a certificate and since we use AWS servers i stumbled across the following article

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pin-application-acm-certificate/

[image]

As you can see above Amazon is saying that it's better to pin a CA, now i didn't find any resource on how to achieve that from Android App side, does any one have a resource for how to achieve it?

Comment: Certificate pinning details depend on what you are using to access the server. For example, [here is how you do it with OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/#certificate-pinning-kt-java).

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah am using OKHttp but i got confused between a normal Certificate and Certificate Authority, what is the difference from Android Side?

Comment: Depending on what you are using (e.g., OkHttp), there may be no difference. OkHttp lets you pin anywhere along the certificate chain, up to and including the root. Personally, I do not like pinning to a public CA, one that anyone can request a certificate from, as that opens up attack vectors. However, I do not know AWS' system, and their CA may be a private one, in which case pinning it is much less risky.